# Installing windows 8 on an 80GB IDE HDD

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

can i install windows7 or 8 (64 bits/32 bits) on an 80 GB IDE HDD?, now that my precious 500GB SATA HDD is damaged i'm gonna have no choice than to pick up my old IDE HDD (XP installed)..
Any exiciting respond???
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could crash the HDD? or maybe because its an old device originally built for windows xp and below. 
couldn't meet up the standard partitioning for the windows 8.
Could be annoying slow and later shit things up......

Comment: @Jaimu, please do a little research before asking.  Also, please spell-check your questions.

Comment: HDDs or SSDs were/are not designed or built for a specific OS. The only function of those storage devices is to hold data.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it works. You'll have very low free diskspace (~40 GB) left after the installation, but it will work.